# What is wrong with this XOR gate layout?

Tags: layout, vlsi

I am learning how to make layout for various CMOS gates in MAGIC. I tried to make layout for a 2 input XOR gate in MAGIC. To the best of my knowledge it should work fine when extracted to SPICE. But when I extract it to spice, use my proper technology files, it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?[image]

After extracting to spice, I did notice that I am getting some "FLOATING" capacitors.

```
*Two Input CMOS XOR gate

.include TSMC_180nm.txt
.param supply = 1.5
.option scale=0.09u
***Netlist***

Vdd vdd GND supply

M1000 notA A gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=28 pd=22 as=124 ps=94
M1001 a_n30_n12# A a_n39_n12# Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=32 pd=24 as=28 ps=22
M1002 a_15_n12# notA a_5_n12# Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=28 pd=22 as=32 ps=24
M1003 notB B gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=28 pd=22 as=0 ps=0
M1004 notB B vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=28 pd=22 as=124 ps=94
M1005 a_79_n12# notB gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=32 pd=24 as=0 ps=0
M1006 a_n30_12# A vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=32 pd=24 as=0 ps=0
M1007 notA A vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=28 pd=22 as=0 ps=0
M1008 a_15_12# notA vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=64 pd=48 as=0 ps=0
M1009 a_38_12# B a_15_12# vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=24 pd=20 as=0 ps=0
M1010 a_38_n12# B gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
+  ad=24 pd=20 as=0 ps=0
M1011 a_79_12# notB a_70_12# vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
+  ad=32 pd=24 as=28 ps=22
C0 gnd m1_4_n12# 0.15fF
C1 notA out 0.10fF
C2 m1_n26_12# vdd 0.34fF
C3 a_n39_n12# m1_n40_n12# 0.01fF
C4 a_5_n12# m1_4_n12# 0.01fF
C5 m1_n40_n12# m1_4_n12# 0.09fF
C6 a_n30_n12# out 0.01fF
C7 notB out 0.10fF
C8 notA vdd 0.14fF
C9 gnd notA 0.04fF
C10 vdd out 1.31fF
C11 gnd out 0.13fF
C12 vdd notA 0.03fF
C13 a_79_12# out 0.01fF
C14 vdd notB 0.15fF
C15 gnd notB 0.09fF
C16 vdd out 0.07fF
C17 m1_n26_12# a_70_12# 0.01fF
C18 vdd vdd 0.37fF
C19 A out 0.01fF
C20 m1_n40_n12# gnd 0.52fF
C21 a_15_n12# out 0.01fF
C22 a_38_12# out 0.01fF
C23 a_15_12# vdd 0.03fF
C24 B out 0.01fF
C25 A vdd 0.19fF
C26 m1_n26_12# a_n30_12# 0.01fF
C27 B vdd 0.19fF
C28 notA m1_4_n12# 0.11fF
C29 m1_4_n12# a_79_n12# 0.01fF
C30 m1_n40_n12# a_38_n12# 0.01fF
C31 m1_n26_12# out 0.04fF
C32 m1_n26_12# notB 0.04fF
C33 m1_n26_12# vdd 1.23fF
*C34 m1_4_n12# Gnd 0.15fF **FLOATING
*C35 m1_n40_n12# Gnd 0.27fF **FLOATING
*C36 out Gnd 0.31fF **FLOATING
*C37 m1_n26_12# Gnd 0.00fF **FLOATING
C38 gnd Gnd 0.27fF
C39 a_15_12# Gnd 0.00fF
C40 vdd Gnd 0.34fF
C41 notB Gnd 0.19fF
C42 B Gnd 0.18fF
C43 notA Gnd 0.21fF
C44 A Gnd 0.28fF
C45 vdd Gnd 4.58fF

Vin1 A GND pulse(0 supply 0 0.5p 0.5p 0.1u 0.2u)
Vin2 B GND pulse(0 supply 0.2u 0.5p 0.5p 0.1u 0.2u)

.control
tran 1p 0.4u
plot v(A) v(B)+3 V(out)+6
.endc
.end
```

When I run the above netlist using ngspice, this is the output I get : [image]

As you can see, if the XOR gate had been functioning correctly, output should have been 7.5 volts when A and B were different and 0 volts when A and B were same but instead I am getting a weird voltage level that is above 7 all the time i.e. 1 volt all the time (since the plot is `v(out) + 6`)

Note: The above netlist has been edited to work with the `TSMC_180nm.txt` technology file I have (as part of a university course). I replaced all the 'pfet' with 'CMOSP' and 'nfet' with 'CMOSN' and connected the body of all PMOS-es to Vdd

Comment: Can you include the SPICE netlist so we can take a look?

Comment: @SteKulov I have included the netlist. Its C34,C35,C36,C37 (I had commented them to try and see if the circuit would work without them, but it doesn't work the right way)

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify what ``But when I extract it to spice, use my proper technology files, it doesn't seem to work`` means. E.g. what are the actual outputs from the SPICE simulation compared to the expected outputs?

Comment: @ChesterGillon I have included a plot of the spice output and explained what I was expecting (to function like an XOR gate)

Comment: Staring at this for the umpteenth time, I notice there are no "× in box" where what I take to be *metal2* & *metal3* overlap diffusion: are the vias there? (The boxed × show with what I think *metal1*.)

Comment: @greybeard no there are no "x" in the box where m2 and m3 overlap diffusion. But I painted them using what I found here  :https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~bbaas/116/docs/magic.layers.html 

Also, what do you mean by "vias"? I tested painting m2 over diffusion using one of the macros and it worked, so I presumed everything is correct.

Comment: I take those symbols at the overlap of light blue (metal1(?)) and the diffusions(light green/brown)/polysilicon(red) to be "holes in an/the oxide layer": vias for electrons to pass through. Depending on how I see diffusion connected to neither \$V_{DD}\$ nor \$V_{SS}\$, no vias would mean the metal2/metal3 nodes float. (I don't know the 1st thing about macros, and mixed up what I didn't forget about MAGIC - it seems to be four decades…)

Comment: I notice the [layers list](https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~bbaas/116/docs/magic.layers.html) hyperlinked above does not contain diff ↔ m3 contacts/vias, stacked or not.

Comment: I think greybeard is on the right track. The layout matches common 12 device XOR. Have you tried to just build a simple inverter with three metal layers connecting to vdd and vss using your reasoning - then sim extracted? If that doesn't work, maybe you are missing some stacking vias or contacts somewhere. Spice extracted netlist looks weird. I think you meant 6 to 7.5 V expected out in your main post (not 0,7.5).

Comment: While I don't think this is your main issue, the default unit in net lists for distance is meters. With a 180nm process, if you try to interface to something real, you may see some weird behavior. That also implies your layout is the literal size of a football field.

Comment: @W5VO there is a .option scale=0.09u at the head of the spicedec. So l=2 and w=4 are,0 .18u and 0.32u if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @pat: `0.18 μm` right `.32` umm…

Comment: @pat You are correct! I never used that before, and I will do my best to avoid using that feature in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update* Very tedious to map - BUT - entire extracted spice circuit with parasitics has been successfully simulated (LTSPICE 1.5V level 1 models). 2 or 3 shorts and floating nodes ignored/warned ( e.g. vdd to vdd cparasitic). So, Layout fine, extracted spicedec fine, that only leaves your model library and or ngspice simulator you are using. Also, I don't see a seperate gnd supply in your netlist (gnd to GND) like you have for VDD, not sure if it matters in ngspice (LTSpice just puts all the grounds to 0 global).

One other observation. I got some weird result with your pulse stimulus (similar to yours, but the two inputs need to be staggered a little). Please try the following, which is what I used

Vin1 A 0 PULSE(0 1.5 .05u 0.5p 0.5p 0.1u 0.2u 5)

Vin2 B 0 PULSE(0 1.5 0.2u 0.5p 0.5p 0.1u 0.2u 5)

### [image]

---

I didn't have time to fully debug the issue as there is a time constraint here.  But, I did verify the layout and circuit function correctly using simple models and 5v process (and ltspice). So, it seems the issue seems to be more related to parasitics and modelling (which could be layout, extraction, and or model related).

Using Magic, you can use the command :extract no capacitance, to [simplify all the work I did here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/magic/tut8.html#94148). Check that the simulation without cap extractions, matches my functional results.

You can try backing out the extra capacitors and seeing if any make significant differences (I did see some of that, but not enough time to fully solve).

I might also have been easier on time and solving the issue if you provided all of the files.

[image]

[image]

slowly adding in parastics. Circuit working fine and most parasitics are trivially small. Just need to add one by one, and try to eliminate where problem is. If they all work, could be model deck.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The netlist does not have any DC connections between the transistors and the output node. You should have the `OUT` node on four drains (2 NMOS, 2 PMOS), and yet it is nowhere to be found. Looking at your output waveform, the issue is either a conflict with pull-up networks and pull-down networks (both active at the same time), or no connection to the output.

Simplifying the capacitances out of the netlist as they should only slow things down and not change the steady-state output of a static CMOS logic gate gives us the following netlist.

Note, the syntax for each line is `<reference> <drain> <gate> <source> <body> <model>`, and drains and sources can be swapped.

```
*** A input inverter
M2 notA A gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
M1 notA A vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
*** B input inverter
M12 notB B vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
M11 notB B gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2

*** A and B NMOS pull-down
M5 a_n30_n12# A a_n39_n12# Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
M6 a_38_n12# B gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
*** ~A and ~B NMOS pull-down
M9 a_15_n12# notA a_5_n12# Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2
M10 a_79_n12# notB gnd Gnd CMOSN w=4 l=2

*** ~A and B PMOS pull-up
M7 a_15_12# notA vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
M8 a_38_12# B a_15_12# vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
*** A and ~B PMOS pull-up
M4 a_79_12# notB a_70_12# vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
M3 a_n30_12# A vdd vdd CMOSP w=4 l=2
```

I used the same notation as pat did in his answer, and I changed the transistor numbers in the netlist to match:

[image]

And what you can see is that there isn't a common output net. Actually, looking at all the nets you can see that many transistors don't have a connected drain or source. I've highlighted all "correct" nets in green, and placed an "X" where a drain or source doesn't connect. (The poly all was fine, so I didn't annotate it)

[image]

So none of your Metal 2 or Metal 3 connections actually connect to the transistors is the conclusion that I come to. Without a key to the layers I can't be sure, but it looks like the connection between the active and Metal 1 is a black box with an X through it. It *should* be visible even with other layers on top. As users graybeard and pat point out, you don't seem to have any contacts in the layout, or they are not being extracted properly.

You need to validate that your layout matches the schematic that you designed. I don't know how to do this in MAGIC, but this kind of tool is called Layout vs. Schematic (LVS)